# __str__ and __repr__ for Integers in Python

Tags: python, string, repr

New to Python. Basic understanding is `__repr__()` gives the object representation/info (I know it sounds silly) of an object while `__str__()` gives the String representation of an object.
When we do call `str()` and `repr()` on an object, seems like it implicitly calls `__str__()` and `__repr__()` implementation for that object.

```
print(repr('3'))        # '3'
print(str('2'))         # 2
print('3'.__repr__())   # '3'
print('2'.__str__())    # 2
```

For String objects, it is making sense but when it comes to integers, I am a bit confused.

```
print(repr(3))   # 3
print(str(2))    # 2
```

I think when we call `repr()` and `str()` on integers, it is calling Python's built-in functions since there is no implementation of `__repr__()` and `__str__()` for Integer Class.
But when I do:

```
print(5.__repr__()) #SyntaxError: invalid syntax
print(5.__str__())  #SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

But,

```
x = 5
print(x.__repr__())  # 5
print(x.__str__())   # 5
```

Shouldn't the last 2 lines also throw an error as above since x is also an Integer? Am I overlooking or missing something that is happening over here?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: "there is no implementation of `__repr__()` and `__str__()` for Integer Class": not really: `dir(2) == ['__abs__', '__add__', ..., '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', ..., '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', ...]`